# Usage problem of attachBeforeOpenContextMenu event in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I would like to fire a context menu event to my list component. I'm using the following coding but it doesn't work. Where I am doing mistake ? Please let me know   about how should I use this event correctly. Here is my codes;
My list component:

```
<List
   id="commentListView"
   items="{/TicketItemModel/COMMENTS}"
   visible="{/TicketCommentListVisibility}"
   mode="SingleSelectMaster"
   includeItemInSelection="true"
   class="todo-comment-list">
   {/* Items here.. */}
</List>
```

My controller.js file:

```
this.getView().byId("commentListView").attachBeforeOpenContextMenu(??,_this.handleShowCommentContextMenu(),??);
```

I don't know exactly which parameters should be passed to the function

Here is my main function code that I called:

```
handleShowCommentContextMenu:function(oEvent){
          var _this = this;
          if(oEvent){
            var listItemBase = oEvent.getSource();
            if(!_this.popupMenu){
              _this.popupMenu = new Menu({
                items:[
                  new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                    text:"Settings",
                    select:function(){
                    }
                  }),
                ]
              })
              _this.getView().addDependent(_this.popupMenu);
            }
            var eDock = sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock;
            _this.popupMenu.open(false, listItemBase, eDock.BeginTop, eDock.BeginBottom, listItemBase);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/attachBeforeOpenContextMenu

The parameters for the function are following:

> attachBeforeOpenContextMenu(oData?, fnFunction, oListener?)

The `?` behind the first and third parameter are indicators that those are optional.
That means, that your code would work just fine, even without them.

`oListener` is an object that (as the text in the link suggests) puts the event into context. You even use the default value `sap.m.ListBase` in your code (`oEvent`)

> Context object to call the event handler with. Defaults to this sap.m.ListBase itself

`oData` is the kind of the model side to `oListener`. While `oListener` is the control element that puts the event into context, the `oData` object is the data that puts the event into context.

I hope i could clearify things for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Erch. I understood your explanation. But when I remove the first and third parameters the function that I called (handleShowCommentContextMenu()) only works once. I'm calling to the function when the onInit() function get fired. It doesn't work on right click action.

Comment: _this.getView().byId("commentListView").attachBeforeOpenContextMenu(function(oEvent){
                  _this.handleShowCommentContextMenu(oEvent);
                });

Comment: It works properly with Table component. But it doesn't work on List component

Comment: if you attach a function that function is called everytime the function you attach it to is called..... i dont see a reason why it should be called just once. please check if the "beforeOpenContextMenu" is really called on button click

Comment: When I set the setContextMenu() function to my list component. It works fine. I guess this function represents "oData" in SapUI5 documentation

Answer (score 0):

In order to open context menu on list item. Firstly you need to define Menu. And then you can set the beforeOpenContextMenu event to the list component in XmlView.

```
_this.getView().byId("commentListView").setContextMenu(new Menu({
     items:[
          new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
          text:"Settings",
          select:function(){
          }
       }),
     ]
}))
```

Comment: If you want to use Menu component as you can see above. You need to define "sap/ui/unified/Menu".